# Arduino. How do I limit the output value of a PID controller?

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

I have the following PID algorithm I snatched from a website whose name I forgot and I need to limit the output such that its maximum value is, let's say, 90. How do I do that? I tried using Arduino's map function but I need to know the maximum value of the output in order to use that. Here's the code:

```
//working variables
unsigned long lastTime;
//double Input, Output, Setpoint;
double errSum, lastErr;
double kp, ki, kd;

void Compute()
{
   //How long since we last calculated
   unsigned long now = millis();
   double timeChange = (double)(now - lastTime);

   //Compute all the working error variables
   double error = Input;
   errSum += (error * timeChange);
   double dErr = (error - lastErr) / timeChange;

   //Compute PID Output
   Output = kp * error + ki * errSum + kd * dErr;
   Output = map(Output, 0, 1500,0,90);

   //Remember some variables for next time
   lastErr = error;
   lastTime = now;
}

void SetTunings(double Kp, double Ki, double Kd)
{
   kp = Kp;
   ki = Ki;
   kd = Kd;
}
```

The call of the map function was added by me as a inefficient way to limit the output.

If it helps you in any way, I want to use it for a balancing robot but weird things happen when the value of the output goes over 90 (the servo library's write() function only accepts values between 0 and 180).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm  not sure how you can map a range to a lower range without knowing the limits of the original range.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I'm asking how to properly limit the output. I just estimated a maximum range in my mapping.

Comment: Lower kp, ki and kd proportionally?

Comment: Add a line to clip the value to 90? `if ( Output > 90) { Output = 90; }`

Comment: then if output goes over 90 and up to, for example 1000, the output still remains 90. I need something proportional, such that if the maximum value of the output is 1000 that value would be equivalent to 90. Anything less than 1000 scales down to anything less than 90. Of course, I do not know the maximum value of the output.

Comment: Could you dynamically set the maximum? For instance, in the main loop: if (Output > max) { max = output}; Then reset the map function?

Comment: Hmmm, I could try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @jrtrzeciak I believe `map()` is hard wired during compilation, it may require 'manual' computation, but the formulae aren't too difficult for that.

Comment: This is a coding question, purely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could clip the output, as suggested by @jippie and @jrtrzeciak or, implement a more advanced approach as discussed below.

When simply limiting the output, an issue is coming from the integral part. When you reach one of your boundaries, the integrator continues to sum up things. And when the output should come back within the allowed range, it takes ages to recover because the I accumulator value became HUGE. This is called an integral windup or a reset windup.

A clever way of dealing with this is to recompute what would have been the I accumulator if the output was at the clipping value. And you replace you I accumulator value with this new value. This approach is a kind of anti-reset windup technique.

The most important here is the wordings. Now you know how to name your issue (integral windup) and you can spend time to find on the web the right mitigation system that is best suited to your application.

There a plenty of example. But you need to know how to look for them...

As an external ressource, a nice example (with code) is given here : http://brettbeauregard.com/blog/2011/04/improving-the-beginner%E2%80%99s-pid-reset-windup/

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically set the maximum, you could try:

```
//Compute PID Output
Output = kp * error + ki * errSum + kd * dErr;
if (Output > maxOutput)
    maxOutput = Output; 
Output = map(Output, 0, maxOutput, 0, 90);
```

Initialize `maxOutput` to 1500 or whatever your guess of the maximum output from the PID will. Then, if it ever exceeds that, it will automatically adjust.